# How to position a button at the bottom center of the screen?

Tags: flutter, textfield

Here is my code, I add some TextFormField in a SingleChildScrollView, and try to put a button at the bottom center of the screen, Expend is not allowed, FloatActionButton will move with the keyboard when text some input, any solution?

```
body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 16),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              const SizedBox(height: 24.0),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'tell me some detail',
                  helperText: 'description'
                ),
                maxLines: 4,
                maxLength: 200,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 48.0),
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'your name here',
                  helperText: 'name'
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                fit: FlexFit.loose,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: (){},
                  child: Text('Submit'),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

[Could I move the button at the right place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNRUy.jpg)

Comment: please follow guidelines when formatting questions on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SafeArea(
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 16),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          const SizedBox(height: 24.0),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder(), hintText: 'tell me some detail', helperText: 'description'),
            maxLines: 4,
            maxLength: 200,
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 48.0),
          TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'your name here', helperText: 'name')),
          Spacer(),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text('Submit'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you use my code? Copy and paste it and see it working

Comment: It looks well until you text something in a input, A warning will at the bottom: BOTTOM OVERFLOWED BY 24 PIXELS. SingleChildScrollView is ok, Padding failed

Comment: OK, got it, in your `Scaffold` add `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false`

Comment: It works well for few text inputs. but when I add a little more inputs, the keyboard will overflow some text filed.

Comment: You should have used `ListView` instead of `Column`

Comment: You should use ListView with Column.

Answer (score 1):

I won't try to decipher your code but you can wrap your button in an Expanded Column and set the column MainAxisAlignment to end

Comment: It seems more like a comment than answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with `SingleChildScrollView` is that it `shrikwrap` it's children. So to have auto size widget in between - we need to use `MediaQuery` to get the screen `height` & `SizedBox` to expand - `SingleChildScrollView`.

Here Button will be at bottom of screen.

Working Code:

```
double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16,),
        child: SizedBox(
          height: height,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              const SizedBox(height: 24.0),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    hintText: 'tell me some detail',
                    helperText: 'description'),
                maxLines: 4,
                maxLength: 200,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 28.0),
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'your name here', helperText: 'name'),
              ),
              Spacer(),
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'your name here', helperText: 'name'),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text('Submit'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

output:

[image]